# Error while reading /proc/$pid/status in python

Tags: python, file-read

I've to read `/proc/pid/status` file to extract `NSpid` field like below:

```
user@user-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ cat /proc/5979/status | grep NSpid
NSpid:  5979    1417
```

I've to extract `1417` from this.

I've tried below:

```
print("Traversing tree")
pid=5947
for c in psutil.Process(pid).children(True):
    cpid=c.pid
    print(str(c.pid))
    with open("/proc/cpid/status",'r') as origin_file:
        for line in origin_file:
            line = re.findall(r'NSpid', line)
            if line:
                line = line[0].split('"')[1]
            print(line)
            break
```

This program is traversing the whole process tree and for each children trying to extract NSpid from status file.
But I'm getting the following error :

```
Traversing tree
5979
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmp.py", line 48, in <module>
    with open("/proc/cpid/status",'r') as origin_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/$cpid/status'
```

How to correct this?

Comment: Is this not a full path? If not then how will it be?

Comment: @r0ei file is there see the command line result it is able to grep that

Comment: 5979 is the first child of 5947

Comment: @r0ei your answer prints an empty line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared a variable called `cpid`, and as I can see you want to use the variable inside the file path, so you can to use `f` strings.

```
cpid=c.pid
print(str(c.pid))
with open(f"/proc/{cpid}/status") as origin_file:
        ...
```

I'm still not sure what the value you want to extract, so here is my solution, I searched for the `NSpid` attribute of the process, and took it's value.

```
...
cpid = c.pid
with open(f"/proc/{cpid}/status") as origin_file:
    for line in origin_file.read().splitlines():
        if line.split()[0] == 'NSpid:':
            print(line.split()[2])
            break
```

And if you want to extract the whole attribute, just change the `print` function

```
# before
print(line.split()[2]) # changed this index from [1] to [2]
# after
print(line)
```

Comment: This is what it is printing now: Traversing tree
5979
[]
5980
[]
5981
[]
5982
[]
5986
[]
5987
[]
5988
[]
5992
[]
5995
[]
5996
[]
5997
[]
5998
[]
6002
[]
6003
[]
6004
[]
6005
[]
6006
[]
6120
[]
6123

Comment: @user13145713 This is your output? And this is what you want to get? if not, what is the excepted output?

Comment: Yes this is my output now

Comment: line will be like this: NSpid:  5979    1417

Comment: and i want to extract 1417 only

Comment: your solution is printing [] on reading the status file but i want like 1417

Comment: @user13145713 So let me understand, you want to extract only the `NSpid`'s value?

Comment: The NSpid line in status file is like this: NSpid: 5979 1417 and i want to extract 1417 from this. I hope you get it now.

Comment: your program works correctly, just change the index from[1] to [2] as i want the second value